# Why do i need to use this user = dict()

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

main_window = Tk()
main_window.title("Register now")

frame = Frame(main_window)
frame.pack()

l_name = Label (frame, text = "Name:")
#metodo entende que é a mesma coisa que l_name.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
l_name.grid()
e_name = Entry(frame)
e_name.grid(row = 0, column =1)

l_lastname = Label(frame, text = "Last name:")
#metodo entende que é a mesma coisa que l_name.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
l_lastname.grid(row = 1)
e_lastname = Entry(frame)
e_lastname.grid(row = 1, column =1)

l_email = Label (frame, text = "E-mail:")
l_email.grid(row = 2)
e_email = Entry(frame)
e_email.grid(row = 2, column =1)

def convert_to_dict():
    user = dict()
    user['name'], user['last_name'], user['e-mail'] = e_name.get(), e_lastname.get(), e_email.get()
    print(user)
    
Button(frame, text = "Send", command = convert_to_dict).grid(row=3,column =1)
```

Why i need this comanda user `= dict()`? I am telling the programn that the variable user is a `dict()` and thats ok, but i want to know if put `user = {}` would do same harm to the code

Comment: `user = dict()` and `user = {}` have the same effect.

Comment: You can also use `user = {"name": e_name.get(), "last__name": e_lastname.get(), ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `user = dict()` creates a new and empty python dictionary which you then fill with content on the subsequent line.

The approach looks rather non-pythonic to me. I would rather initialize and fill the dictionary in one go as *TheLizzard* suggested:

```
user = {"name": e_name.get(), "last__name": e_lastname.get(), ...}
```

You can achieve the same thing with the `dict()` method but it may result in more visual clutter in this case. However, the `dict()` method comes with a bunch of other handy ways to create and fill dictionaries in programmatic ways. e.g. this resource gives a nice overview: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary